# Can I safely trample my saplings?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121473/do-flowers-heal) we know that flowers can be healed from careless trampling through watering, and that walking over flowers don't hurt them, but does the same apply to saplings?

Saplings 'bounce' when you walk over them (similar to flowers), and I don't want to accidentally kill it by running over them.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, haven't tested that extensively. Saplings should only die when placed too close to other stuff or boxed in by other trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot kill a sapling by running over them.  There is no need to water them or anything.  I tested this by running over the sapling extensively and it grew fine.

Comment: Does this apply to juvenile fruit trees and bushes as well?  Or just purchased saplings?